# Resharper multiline method invocation parenthesis alignment

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper is formatting multiline method calls like this:

```
foo.Bar(
    x,
    y
    );
```

I would prefer it to align the closing parenthesis with the first line e.g.:

```
foo.Bar(
    x,
    y
);
```

I've looked through the Resharper code layout options, but cannot see the right setting. Can someone tell me how to achieve this alternative formatting?

Comment: My opinion, but I think it's weird and confusing to use parenthesis like curly braces.

Comment: I'd be pretty interested in the outcome of this too. Resharper for me tends to put the closing `;` on it's own orphaned line sometimes too...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, go to Resharper > Options > Languages > C# > Formatting Style > Other > Indentation > Continuous line indent multiplier and set it to 0.

Comment: Almost, but this does not indent the arguments. Everything is aligned with the start of the variable, instead of just the closing parenthesis.

Comment: It seems this is not currently possible with ReSharper, though it appears to be in the works. See the answer I posted on a related question here: [Resharper closing parenthesis indentation on function with multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637290/resharper-closing-parenthesis-indentation-on-function-with-multiple-arguments/30129366#30129366)

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend you take a look at **StyleCop**, and then **StyleCop for ReSharper**?

StyleCop allows you to create exceptions or warnings for various types of formatting. The latter project, StyleCop for ReSharper allows ReSharper to automatically implement certain formats.  There is quite a steep learning curve initially with SfR, but it is well worthwhile.  This is a very under-used tool, and I wish Microsoft would advertise StyleCop more.

Both are Codeplex projects, and can be found at their respective URL's:

- http://stylecop.codeplex.com/
- http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/

I hope this helps you out somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

In 2016.2 version appeared an option *Intent method calls' parenthesis*.

It does exactly what you expect:

[image: screenshot]