# Resharper closing parenthesis indentation on function with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, resharper

I have some lines of code in c# that Resharper indents like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
this.MySuperFunction(
  argument1,
  argument2,
  argument3
  );
Console.WriteLine("World");
```

Due to my personal coding style, I would like the above to appear with the closing parenthesis (or brace) without any indentation, like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
this.MySuperFunction(
  argument1,
  argument2,
  argument3
);
Console.WriteLine("World");
```

I tried playing with the various options on Resharper, but couldn't find any. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: that always bugged me too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resharper multiline method invocation parenthesis alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352708/resharper-multiline-method-invocation-parenthesis-alignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to 2016.2 version. An option *Intent method calls' parenthesis* appeared in this version:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It only took 1.5 year!

Answer (score 5):

It seems this is not currently possible with ReSharper. There is however an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427585) that appears to be slated for release with version 9. If you're interested in raising awareness to the issue and hope to ensure it gets included in the release I recommend you create an account and up vote the issue.

Comment: Thanks for linking the youtrack issue.